# .Net How To Get Common Elements in List by Count

Tags: .net, list, linq, lambda, count

I want something like this but it doesn't compile:

```cs
List<uint> numbers = new List<uint> { 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7};
var List_Of_Count_4_Elements = numbers.Where(x => x.Count() == 4).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

// The result should look like this:
List_Of_Count_4_Elements[0] == 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
List<uint> numbers = new List<uint> { 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7};
var List_Of_Count_4_Elements = numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 4).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

You can group the items and then you can find out which number is four times in your list.

Comment: ahh that compiles so GroupBy() enables the Count() to finally show up. :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

[demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AgHfwe)

You need to group by first.

```
    List<uint> numbers = new List<uint> { 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7};
    var Max_Elements_Count = 4;

    var result1 = numbers.GroupBy(p => p)
                        .Where(x => x.Count() == Max_Elements_Count)
                        .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();   

    var result2 = numbers.GroupBy(p => p, (k, group) =>  new { Key = k, Element_Count = group.Count() })
                         .Where(x => x.Element_Count == Max_Elements_Count).ToList();


    var result3 = (from n in numbers
                  group n by n into groupList
                  where  groupList.Count() == Max_Elements_Count
                  select groupList.Key).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(result1[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(result2[0].Key);
    Console.WriteLine(result3[0]);
```

Comment: I gave you some ways to achieve it, please take a look at @user51902